# How to allow big file size upload using .NET Core MVC with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-core

I am using .NET Core 3.1 MVC with C# to a make web application. I want to allow users to upload files with the unlimited file size to my server.

I tried the following things:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15431

[Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Remember my main goal is allow to upload any file size.

I also tried

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        //[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 107374182400)] //100 GB
        //[RequestSizeLimit(107374182400)]
        //[DisableRequestSizeLimit, RequestSizeLimit(107374182400)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ImportDB(int t = 0)
        {}
```

It works for Linux based server but not work for IIS server

My web.config file for 4 GB. **I want unlimited file size.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />   
    <!-- Add this section for file size... -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <!--Measured in Bytes--> 
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
         <!--4 GB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you tried zero(0) value for "maxAllowedContentLength" ?

Comment: No. Should I try with 0.?

Comment: try it. somtimes zero value works for limitation to unlimited. like "timeout"

Comment: Not working: https://i.imgur.com/cnsSU0h.png
HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/440509/getting-around-the-fat32-4gb-file-size-limit

Comment: First of all you should not be allowing any size of file to upload and secondly if you still want then compress it  and then upload the file in the max limit of the iis.

Answer (score -1):

The size of the uploaded file is an important factor in considering storage capacity. It is not allowed that end users to upload files of unlimited size, because in the worst case, this will only cause one user to fill up the server storage capacity.

If you want to upload a very large file, maybe you can try to split the file into smaller parts for uploading. Here is the reference: [Uploading and Downloading large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502286/uploading-and-downloading-large-files-in-asp-net-core-3-1)