# Upload and download huge files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, download, upload

I have an API application (server side: C# ASP.NET Core 7, client side: React).

I need to allow downloading files and uploading files, up to 5 GB.
How would you recommend I do this?

I understand that recommended to do this asynchronously and with streaming. (and uploaded with chunk).

I tried some sample code snippets from the internet and it didn't work properly.

I would be happy to help both how it should be and if you can give me an example that works.

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62502286/uploading-and-downloading-large-files-in-asp-net-core-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

**File Upload**

In ASP.NET Core MVC, the maximum upload result for file upload is 20MB by default. If we want to upload some relatively large files, let's see how to install it.

Step 1 Without WebConfig:

To set the file upload size limit to 40 MB, we need to add the following code to the ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 40000000;//40MB
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).